# How to seperate Tkinter Gui app source code into multiple files

Tags: python, function, tkinter, import, toplevel

i'm working on downloading manager python gui app using Tkinter and halfway there my code started to look very messy so i decided to seperate functions on different file and then import it:
my main code:

```
from tkinter import *
from functions import add_download

root = Tk()
root.title("The Pownloader!")
canvas = Canvas(root, width=700, height=500).pack()

# Buttons:

ADD_BUTTON = Button(root, text="ADD", bd=4, height=2, width=5, command=add_download)
SETTINGS_BUTTON = Button(root, text="SETTINGS", bd=4, height=2, width=5)
ABOUT_BUTTON = Button(root, text="ABOUT", bd=4, height=2, width=5)
EXIT_BUTTON = Button(root, text="EXIT", bd=4, height=2, width=5, command=quit)

# Mini-Buttons:

PAUSE_MINI_BUTTON = Button(root, text="PAUSE", font=(None, "8"), height=2, width=3)
RESUME_MINI_BUTTON = Button(root, text="RESUME", font=(None, "8"), height=2, width=3)
REMOVE_MINI_BUTTON = Button(root, text="REMOVE", font=(None, "8"), height=2, width=3)

# Side_Mini_Buttons:

DOWNLOAD_WINDOW = Button(root, text="Downloads", font=(None, "8"), height=3, width=6)
ERRORS_WINDOW = Button(root, text="Failed", font=(None, "8"), height=3, width=6)
COMPLETED_WINDOW = Button(root, text="Completed", font=(None, "8"), height=3, width=6)

# Positionning Buttons:

ADD_BUTTON.place(x=70, y=20)
SETTINGS_BUTTON.place(x=145, y=20)
ABOUT_BUTTON.place(x=220, y=20)
EXIT_BUTTON.place(x=295, y=20)
PAUSE_MINI_BUTTON.place(x=290, y=455)
RESUME_MINI_BUTTON.place(x=340, y=455)
REMOVE_MINI_BUTTON.place(x=390, y=455)
DOWNLOAD_WINDOW.place(x=1, y=100)
ERRORS_WINDOW.place(x=1, y=160)
COMPLETED_WINDOW.place(x=1, y=220)

# Download Frame:

DOWNLOAD_LIST_LABEL = Label(root, text="Download List:")
DOWNLOAD_LIST_LABEL.place(x=70, y=80)
DOWNLOAD_ENTRIES = Listbox(root, width=70, height=19)
DOWNLOAD_ENTRIES.place(x=70, y=100)


# Main Loop:

root.mainloop()
```

However my functions.py code looks like this:

```
def add_download():
    # Defining The Pop-up frame:
    
    top = Toplevel(root, width = 420, height = 150)
    top.title("New Download")

    # Putting on widgets:
    link = StringVar()
    LINK_LABEL = Label(top, text = "Paste Link:")
    FIELD_ENTRY = Entry(top, width = 40, textvariable=link)

    def on_click():
        link_to_verify = (link.get()).strip()
        if len(link_to_verify)>15:
            if link_to_verify[0:11]=="http://www.":
                DOWNLOAD_ENTRIES.insert(0, link_to_verify)
            else:
                print("Stupid")
        else:
            print("not a valid link")

    BUTTONS_WIDGET = Frame(top)
    ADD_BUTTON = Button(BUTTONS_WIDGET, text = "Add", width=10, command=on_click)
    CANCEL_BUTTON = Button(BUTTONS_WIDGET, text = "Cancel", width=10, command=top.destroy)

    # Positionning everythig:
    LINK_LABEL.grid(column=0,row=0)
    FIELD_ENTRY.grid(column=1,row=0)
    BUTTONS_WIDGET.grid(column=1,row=2)
    ADD_BUTTON.grid(column=0,row=0)
    CANCEL_BUTTON.grid(column=1,row=0)
```

basically i wanted the function to call and show a pop-up window, i'm sure this could done in a million times better but i'm just learning, however i receive an error says:
**Toplevel is not defined**

Comment: Every file needs to import tkinter

Comment: when i import tkinter on the other file, it says root is not defined

Comment: That's a separate problem.

Answer (score 1):

Every file needs to import tkinter.

In addition, any variables in the main file which are needed by the imported functions need to be passed into the functions. For example, you should define `add_download` to accept the root window as a parameter.

```
def add_download(root):
    ...
```

Then, in the main program, pass `root` as that parameter:

```
ADD_BUTTON = Button(root, ..., command=lambda: add_download(root))
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to build a class to manage it.

Inside run.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from interface import GUI

root = tk.Tk()
GUI(root)
```

Then inside your interface.py script you can call in additional modules:

```
import tkinter as tk
from aux import AuxGUI
from menu import MenuGUI 

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.GUI_list = []
        self.AuxGUI = AuxGUI(self.master, self.GUI_list)  # Additional module
        self.MenuGUI = MenuGUI (self.master, self.GUI_list)  # Additional module
```

Then you can use OOP to access functions or objects to dynamically interact with each other.

```
 self.GUI_list.append(self.AuxGUI)
 self.GUI_list.append(self.MenuGUI)
```

Inside menu.py identify the correct index from the GUI_list:

```
 import tkinter as tk

 class MenuGUI:
     def __init__(self, master, GUI_list):
         self.master = master
         self.AuxGUI = GUI_list[0]
```

Comment: I think saying they _need_ a class to manage it is a bit strong. It's certainly possible to solve this problem without classes.

Comment: With your technique. Are you able to edit an object in an imported module from a function in a different imported module? Or would your technique only work on the primary script?

Comment: Your question is too vague to answer. Yes, it's possible to modify objects that have been passed in from other modules. Yes, using classes to define an app makes this easier, but it's not strictly necessary.